# The behavior between ui-threads messagequeue, looper and the handler class

Tags: android, handler, message-queue, looper

I post this question because i wanna know if my thoughts are right about the basics.

What should be clear is that the UI-Thread contains a `MessageQueue`, which is associated with a `Looper` to get messages/runnables out of the queue for processing.

Furthermore a `Handler` sends messages/runnables to the `Looper`, which integrates the object in the `MessageQueue`.

If im right the `MessageQueue` is the stack and the `Looper` is the caretaker of the incoming and outgoing objects.

This leads to my next question. If a message object is processed by the UI-Thread, it will be recycled to the global message pool. But theres no explicit documentation about this. Is there a specific size for this message pool? Is it expandable/shrinkable if i send/obtain messages?

If this would be true the pool could dry out by obtaining to many messages. And i cant believe this. Think about a situation where you have to obtain some messages without sending them back for recycling in a specific time period.

Edited to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the source code of [Handler](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Handler.java) and [Message](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/Message.java) in the framework to see the details on how this works.

In short, the pool is a linked list of `Message` objects (up to `MAX_POOL_SIZE`) that will be filled by the the `recycle()` method. The `obtain()` methods simply checked the pool first of any available `Message` that can be reused and just allocate a new one if none is available.